# testing my applcation with junit

Tags: java, junit

I'm a newbie of testing world and I'm starting to testing my application with junit.I have a class

```
public class Sender implements Runnable
{
   private httpd server;

   public Sender(httpd server_)
   {
     this.server = server_
   }

   public void run()
   {

     ...    

   }
}
```

I would test if the reference received from the `httpd` class is `null`. I read I have to use `assertNotNull` but I have not clear what do do after having created SenderTest class.
I read to create inside SenderTest class (created through junit framework) a method having annotation `@Test`.but after that what I have to do?

Comment: Can you also add your 'test' code

Comment: If you want to assert that a parameter to your method is not null, that sounds like input validation, not unit testing. That should be an assertion in class Sender. For unit tests, you would call the class Sender and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the way you should test your class.

Whether or not `httpd` is null is not part of the contract of `Sender` but the clients of `Sender`.

I suggest you do the following:

- Define how `Sender` should behave if it receives `null` as `server_` argument.

  I would recommend for instance saying something like *If `server_` is `null`, an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.*.
- Create a test which asserts that it behaves as specified. For instance by doing something like

  ```
  try {
      new Sender(null);
      fail("Should not accept null argument");
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException expected) {
  }
  ```

Comment: +1. Unit tests check if `Sender` works. Not if other code uses `Sender` correctly. That would be input validation, maybe using the `assert` keyword.

Comment: So if my class have a reference with other class, I can't testing its behave, right?

Comment: Sure you can. What behavior is it that you want to test?

Comment: I would to test if the class Sender receive the correct object httpd

Comment: But that is not the responsibility of `Sender` right? That is the responsibility of the *user* of sender (the class that calls `new Sender(...)`). So test the *user* of sender to ensure this, not `Sender`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use JUnit to test your code, consider this approach.

This is an example of how the JUnit tests should work:

---

```
public class Factorial {

    /**
     * Calculates the factorial of the specified number in linear time and constant space complexity.<br>
     * Due to integer limitations, possible calculation of factorials are for n in interval [0,12].<br>
     * 
     * @param n the specified number
     * @return n!
     */
    public static int calc(int n) {
        if (n < 0 || n > 12) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Factorials are defined only on non-negative integers.");
        }

        int result = 1;

        if (n < 2) {
            return result;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            result *= i;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

---

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class FactorialTest {

    @Test
    public void factorialOfZeroShouldBeOne() {
        assertEquals(1, Factorial.calc(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void factorialOfOneShouldBeOne() {
        assertEquals(1, Factorial.calc(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void factorialOfNShouldBeNTimesFactorialOfNMinusOne() {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++) {
            assertEquals(i * Factorial.calc(i - 1), Factorial.calc(i));
            System.out.println(i + "! = " + Factorial.calc(i));
        }
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void factorialOfNegativeNumberShouldThrowException() {
        Factorial.calc(-1);
        Factorial.calc(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void factorialOfNumberGreaterThanTwelveShouldThrowException() {
        Factorial.calc(13);
        Factorial.calc(20);
        Factorial.calc(50);
    }
}
```